# how to change the font size of adminition sector font size of mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'd like to change the left part: the administration sector font size. I couldn't find a good way to change that online. Could anyone help me on that.

I use mysql workbench 8.0.27 on centos 7.9.

Here is my screenshot.

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming questions. For software usage, please try the superuser site instead.

Comment: @MatBailie: From ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "software tools commonly used by programmers" -- MySQL Workbench well qualifies as a software tool commonly used by MySQL database programmers, I believe. So this question is on-topic here IMHO.